# How to add a Class and a Database in UML

Tags: uml, plantuml

I'm trying to create in UML a `class` called `LocalStorageHandler` that handles a `database` called `LocalStorage`, and i'm getting a syntax error.
This is my uml code:

```
@startuml
package SomeGroup {
    class "LocalStorageHandler" {
    }

    database "LocalStorage" {
    }
}
@enduml
```

and this is the error message:
[image: the error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can shoehorn that in by using a `package` with the `Database` stereotype:

```
@startuml
package SomeGroup {
    class "LocalStorageHandler" {
    }
    package LocalStorage <<Database>> {
    }
}
@enduml
```

[image]

Alternatively, as Thomas Kilian noted, and to stay within UML specifications and have it remain a class, you can of course use an arbitrary stereotype on the class definition:

```
@startuml
package SomeGroup {
    class "LocalStorageHandler" {
    }
    class LocalStorage <<ArbitraryStereotype>> {
    }
}
@enduml
```

[image]